DNP3 Simulator attempt using WPF. Exception Could not load file or assembly 'DNP3CLRAdapter
Exception here:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'DNP3CLRAdapter, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

This .dll does exist and I even added it as a resource.  I am using OpenDNP3 package, installed directly from NuGet.  Any idea what I am doing wrong or what I can do to fix this?
I did find something on the web about getting library files from OpenSSL. I installed it and got these two dll's.  libcrypto-3.dll and libssl-3.dll. But that didn't fix the issue.
